# Error : Get-AzRoleAssignement : Cannot find principal using the specified options

Tags: azure, powershell

Can some one help to get the details of all users from Azure for their Role assignement with `-ExpandPrincipalGroups`.

I have tried for one user and it is working fine but when i run the query for all azusers then it gives an error.

Here is the command I am trying:

**$user = (Get-AzADUser).UserPrincipalname**

**Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $user -ExpandPrincipalGroups | Select-Object DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName, Scope**

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $user -ExpandPrincipalGroups | Select-Object DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName, Scope
Get-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot find principal using the specified options
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $user -ExpandPrincipalGroups | Selec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzRoleAssignment], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.GetAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome back suri,

you need to pass the parameter `SignInName` of the command `Get-AzRoleAssignment` as string not a list

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment
   -SignInName <String>
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   [-RoleDefinitionName <String>]
   [-IncludeClassicAdministrators]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

so this could be handled as follow

```
(Get-AzADUser).UserPrincipalname | % { Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $_  | Select-Object DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName,Scope}

DisplayName    RoleDefinitionName        Scope                                              
-----------    ------------------        -----                                              
Mahmoud Moawad Owner                     /subscriptions/XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX
Mahmoud Moawad User Access Administrator /
```

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud Moawad . you are genius

Comment: I have written this command:


`Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $SID -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ResourceName $RN -ResourceType Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups -RoleDefinitionName "Desktop Virtualization User"`
                                                       
But still getting error as **Cannot find principal using the specified options**.   Please help me in this.