# Is there a way to show displayName with Get-AzRoleAssignment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Hello I am trying to get a list of all my role assignments after resource deployment in my CI/CD pipeline. However the `displayName` field is always empty in my response.
I am using:

`Get-AzRoleAssignment -scope $res_id`

I have tried using object ids instead and it is the same. I wonder why `displayName` is left blank? Does anyone know how to retrieve the `displayName`?

Comment: Hi Chris; can I ask what kind of displayName are you hoping to get back? Azure role assignments don't really *have* a display name of their own; all they are is a scope, an object, and a role.

Comment: @VinceBowdren The displayName is the user or group. It is for documentation purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following permission Directory.Read.All was added by my Azure AD and Graph supervisor and that solved the problem. Thanks so much for inputs

Comment: Note that you need Application permission for this (not delegated).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment. I’m able to retrieve the `displayName` with `Get-AzRoleAssignment` successfully.

[image]

Try using the cmdlet like below:

> Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $res | Select-Object
> DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName

If you want to retrieve the `displayName` of only your role assignments, include your `SignInName`(your login mail to Azure).

[image]

Try using the cmdlet like below:

> Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName yoursigninmail -Scope $res |
> Select-Object DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName

If you still get `displayName` as blank, you need to configure the resource an `Access Policy`. The RBAC permissions to the resource are not enough and managed separately as Access Policies.

For more information, go through below links.

**References:**

[Get-AzRoleAssignment (Az.Resources) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-7.2.0)

[azure - Error : Get-AzRoleassignment : Cannot find principal using the specified options - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640286/error-get-azroleassignement-cannot-find-principal-using-the-specified-option)

[Assign-an-access-policy-to-the-resource | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal#assign-an-access-policy)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however I am an external developer and I get an error when using signinname. This is also run during a DevOps build pipeline

Comment: Hi @ChrisJeppesen, You can use the DevOps project service principal as signin name to Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName cmdlet